# Setting up ngrok an homestad

Tags: homestead, ngrok

I am trying to setup ngrok on my homestead, but it is not opening my project.
I have run `ngrok http 80` and copied the address in forwarding part of the output to my Homestead.yaml file to map it to my project, and ran vagrant provision after that:

```
Forwarding                    http://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
Forwarding                    https://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
```

But when I open the http://92832de0.ngrok.io in the browser it opens up ngrok page "It works" and not my project.

When I have changed the port to `ngrok http 8000` then I get Laravel error message:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Answer (score 18):

You can use any of your application which is in homestead.
For that, you need to run the below command by replacing 'your-site.app:8000'

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite your-site.app:8000
```

Before that, you need to register into ngrok and install ngrok then use the authtoken that given in your account.

For more details, refer this https://ngrok.com/docs

Comment: SUPER helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: after running the above command, i get nginx 403 forbidden ... any help?? for url http://8219a451.ngrok.io/ .... ngrok dashboard also shows "gzip: invalid header"

Answer (score 6):

This is how It worked for me:

**1)** I have downloaded the `ngrok` (https://ngrok.com/) on my Windows host machine and executed `ngrok.exe`.
It has opened a command line interface for me

**2)** I typed the following

```
ngrok.exe http 192.168.10.10 -host-header=homestead.test
```

And it gave me the link of where to go:

> Forwarding                    http://123456.ngrok.io -> http://192.168.10.10:80
>
> Forwarding                    https://123456.ngrok.io -> http://192.168.10.10:80

I just went there ans saw my local environment Laravel Project.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a function like this to your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile script on the host machine:

```
rock(){
  ngrok http 192.168.10.10:80 -host-header=$1
}
```

After that you can use it to proxify any site on your Homestead machine like this:

```
rock your-site.app:8000
```

Comment: Much easier to remember like this. Only thing I added was ability to allow me to pass other arguments `ngrok http 192.168.10.10:80 -host-header=$1 ${@:2}`

Comment: Nailed the method name :'D

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sites on your homestead you have to:

1. ssh into your homestead.
2. run this command: `share yoursite.test`

and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In homestead ngrok is already installed by default,
You just need to create an account from ngrok at https://dashboard.ngrok.com/signup

And then run:

- vagrant up (in folder Homestead)
- vagrant ssh
- cd to/your/project/proyect
- ngrok authtoken your__ngrok__account___token
- share yourproject.test